# How to load UTF-8 CSV files using Bulk Insert and an XML Format file in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert, sql-server-2017

After much trying, I have found that since `SQL server 2017` (2016?), loading UTF-8 encoded CSV files through Bulk Insert has become possible by using the options `CODEPAGE = 65001` and `DATAFILETYPE = 'Char'`, as explained in some other questions.

What doesn't seem to work, is doing the same when using an XML formatfile. I have tried this by still using the CODEPAGE and DATAFILETYPE options, and also with these options omited. And I have tried this with the most simple dataset. One row, one column, containing some text with an UTF-8 character.

This is the XML Formatfile I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="STREET" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="1000" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CS_AS_WS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="STREET" NAME="STREET" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Even through the source data only contains some text with 1 special character, the end result looks like this: `慊潫ⵢ瑓晥慦⵮瑓慲鿃⁳㐱`
When using `xsi:type="CharTerm"` instead of `xsi:type="NCharTerm"` the result looks like this: ...`-StraÃŸs` ...

Am I doing something wrong, or has UTF-8 support not been properly implemented for XML format files?

Comment: Try adding the UTF-8 BOM to the CSV file.

Comment: Rationale: Windows tools often rely on the UTF-8 BOM to decide between ANSI and UTF-8 when reading text files - for example, Excel does it for CSV - this might also be the case here. And `ÃŸ` is what happens when an UTF-8-encoded `ß` is read as ANSI (Windows-1252), so wrong input encoding selection is what happens here.

Comment: @Tomalak : Good suggestion, I had also been playing around with that already. Re-tested it now. When using BOM, and omitting the CODEPAGE parameter, the BOM ends up in the first row (values still with messed up encoding). Yet, this show us that the CODEPAGE parameter is actually being used when using an XML formatfile, and when using CODEPAGE 65001, a BOM header is expected (or at least not unexpected)

Comment: That leaves us the xsi:type to play around with. When using NCharTerm I get the chinese character, when using CharTerm, I get the ÃŸ. My guess now is that multiple sequential encoding conversions are being performed. First by the bulk insert command, then by the xsi:type parameter in the FIELD tag, and maybe another time in the COLUMN tag... Too bad Microsoft didn't add documentation for this...

Comment: It's not quite that mysterious. The file is treated as binary until the point when a conversion to string takes place. When an UTF-8 file is interpreted as Windows-1252, then `ß` becomes `ÃŸ`, because `ß` is two bytes in UTF-8. When the same UTF-8 file is interpreted as UTF-16, then those Chinese characters come out, because in UTF-16 all characters have two bytes, and the UTF-8 byte sequence for `"Jakob-Steffa"` (12 characters, 1 byte each) is `4A 61 6B 6F 62 2D 53 74 65 66 66 61`, which is equivalent to the byte sequence for `"慊潫ⵢ瑓晥慦"` in UTF-16 (six characters, two bytes each).

Comment: What I'm still confused about is where exactly conversions take place. There's the bulk insert encoding settings, then there's the FIELD-tag xsi:type setting, together with the COLLATION setting, and then there's the xsi:type tag for the COLUMN-tag. The settings in the bulk insert command seem to determine how the file is interpreted, and the settings in the FIELD-tag seem to trigger ... a conversion? Not sure here...

Comment: You could continue to fiddle with the bcpformat settings, or you could give in and convert the CSV to UTF-16 before importing it, and thus deliver the assumed format. You know for a fact that it originally is UTF-8. So, for a one-off you can use a text editor like Notepad++. It's also easily possible with Powershell: `Get-Content original.csv -Encoding UTF8 -Raw | Out-File utf16.csv -Encoding unicode`

Comment: Oh, I guess you missed the answer I've posted to my own question ;) I have been fiddling, and found the culprit. Just not sure how to explain *why* it works.

Comment: Yes, I missed that. I had the tab open from yesterday and the answer wasn't visible until I reloaded. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with this, I have found the solution.

**Notes**

- This works with or without BOM header. It is irrelevant.
- The culprit was using the COLLATION parameter in the XML file. Omitting it solved the encoding problem. I have an intuitive sense as to why this is the case, but maybe someone with more insight could explain in the comments...
- The `DATAFILETYPE = 'char'` option doesn't seem necessary.
- In the XML file, the `xsi:type` for the field needs to be CharTerm, **not** NCharTerm.
- This works with \r\n, \n, or \r. As long as you set the TERMINATOR correctly, this works. No \n\0 variations required (this would even break functionality, since this is not UTF-16 or UCS-2).

Below you can find a proof-of-concept for easy reuse...

**data.txt**

```
ß
ß
ß
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST](
    TEST [nvarchar](500) NULL
)
```

**formatfile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="20"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="TEST" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

**Bulk insert**

```
    bulk insert TEST..TEST
    from 'data.txt'
    with (formatfile = 'formatfile.xml', CODEPAGE = 65001)
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your terminator to `TERMINATOR="\r\0\n\0"`. You have to account for the extra bytes when using NCharTerm.

Comment: There are no null bytes in in UTF-8 (yes, there is `\0`, as a stand-alone character. But there is not `\r\0` as the carriage return).

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. Rationale: Answers that you haven't tested (and are wrong), are not constructive on StackOverflow in this format. You should post them as comments, clearly indicating it's merely an educated guess.